# Converting text to Title case in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way to convert a block of text to title case in Notepad++?

It should turn

> asdf ASDF aSdF

into

> Asdf Asdf Asdf

I see upper case and lower case on the edit menu, but those aren't quite what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The TextFX plugin has this feature, they call it "Proper Case". You can find it under **TextFX -> TextFX Characters -> Proper Case**:

[image]

Comment: Does this have a Hotkey?

Comment: @Homer - you can assign one in `Plugin Commands` section of **Shortcut Mapper**. Item `Proper case` is present there, waiting for you :)

Comment: You no longer need the TextFX plugin to convert between casing styles. Notepad++ has it "natively". It's under `Edit | Convert case to`

Comment: Alt-U is the shortcut.

Comment: The last comment should be in accepted answer.

Answer (score 14):

You can use replace text by regular expression:

[image]

Explanation:

Search text

- `\<` matches the beginning of a word
- `(\w+)` matches any sucession of word letters

Substituted by

- `\L` translates everything to lowercase until the end of the replacement string
- `\u` translates the next letter to uppercase
- `\1` places the first captured () search group

  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKtZH.png):

Answer (score 10):

As the way has changed in the meantime here is how it works now (without TextFX):

Select the case you want to convert, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> or choose

**Edit - Convert Case to - Title Case**.

[image: Convert Case to - Title Case]

[image: Converting to Title Case]

Comment: I do not have this menu at NPP 7.5.4 (32-bit). How does one get this? Thank you.

Comment: In the 64-bit version of 7.5.4 it is available. Maybe you want to use this version.

Comment: Thank you. Can you suggest a plugin to get a proper Title Case (first word capitalized, and all other words, except for articles, prepositions and conjunctions)?

Comment: I do not think this exists. You could paste your text into a translation program like [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/) or [DeepL](https://deepl.com/translator) and translate back and forth. Maybe this helps a bit. But you will have to verify it manually afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't install the TextFX plug in you can create a macro that does something very close:

Place your cursor near a word, and click the red dot on the tool bar, or Macro>Start Recording.

1. Use the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> (left arrow key), to select the whole word
2. Make it lowercase (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>).
3. Press <kbd>←</kbd> to go to the front of the word.
4. Highlight the first letter (using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> *once*)
5. Uppercase that,  (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>).

Press the black square, or go to Macro>Stop Recording. In the same section on the tool bar you should see a button with a floppy disk on it (alternatively there is an option in the macro menu). Press that and assign a hot key, I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to keep in mind with this.  The TextFX plug-in is only in the ANSI version.  You will need to download the ZIP file and copy the contents of the ANSI directory to your computer.  For some reason, the .exe only installs the unicode without a few key plug-ings.

Comment: no longer true.